# Page numbers reversed from 10 - Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page, numbering

I have a strange thing in Indesign. I put automatic page numbers in my master A both for the left page as for the right page.

On the right pages everything is ok, but on the left pages as from "10", Indesign puts 01 - 21 - 31 - 41... instead of 10 - 12 - 13 - 14... I removed the placeholder and put it back, but the problem stays.

Can anybody help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the folio on the left pages has the wrong *Paragraph direction* or *Character direction*?

[image]

[image]

Anyway the style of the left folio seems to be different than the style of the right folio.

Try to apply the style of the right folio to the left, or simply copy/paste the *Current Page Number Marker* from the right page to the left page.

Comment: It worked by copy/paste the marker, but as soon as I tried to apply some paragraph styling it changed again. I stopped at the point where it's working!

Comment: Have you checked if right-to-left direction is part of the style?